# How to change output value from BSDatepicker as we configure format?

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular6

I am using BSDatepicker for the calendar. when I format my date like YYYYMMDD (20180728) it shows me on the date picker but while submitting the form it shows me :

```
{
  "date": "2018-07-28T13:04:07.000Z"
}
```

I need to submit the data as shown in the UI that is BsConfig format. Any solution on view part?

Comment: the way it's sent now is exactly the specification in which datetime should be passed in JSON.  this way, it can seamlessly serialize to a DateTime object, in your backend.  why would you want to override that with custom implementation of your own ?

Comment: @stavm I have a bunch of fields including start date and end dates and the API will support only the YYYYMMDD format only so. And I am using angular template form so..

Comment: @sudar - did you find a solution?

Comment: @Farasi78 Not yet.. will look into it

Comment: @sudar did my suggestion below not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would submit it as a string, and use the DatePipe to transform it to your required value:

You can see an example here: [Code Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvubkt)
In your component:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
constructor(private dp:DatePipe)


var tempDate:string = this.dp.transform(myDate, 'yyyyMMdd');
```

then submit tempDate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolve in the controller part by using :

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
formatDate(mydate.value.effDate, 'yyyyMMdd', 'en')
```

I am using angular 6. It might be new in this version. This might be helpful for others